How to do a catch-all layout.tsx in Next.js App Router?
I'm building a tools website that serves as a toolset, so there are MANY tools
I want to fetch the metadata for them automatically by slug which is dynamic
Right now I have the tools routes structured like this
/app/tools/category/tool-name/page.tsx
Example: /app/tools/ai/keyword-extractor/page.tsx
I created a catch-all layout.tsx at /app/tools/[...slug]/layout.tsx
But can't figure out how to add Metadata for the tools automatically
Again I may have thousands of tools in the future I don't want thousands of layout.tsx files for each tool
Can this be done automatically in the approach I'm attempting?
Thank you

You can use generateMetadata function to dynamically generate metadata for each route of your layout, the function needs to be called inside your layout component, which has to be rendered server-side (don't include "use client" at the top), { params } will be the object that contains slug as an array (e.g. { params: { slug: ["ai", "keyword-extractor"] }}). You will have to store the metadata somewhere in your application, or an external service (e.g. Database).
There are ways to implement this in an optimal way by combining generateMetadata with generateStaticParams.
